# Check if time difference is less than 45 mins and run function - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

This is an easy thing to do in PHP with code like this;

```
if (strtotime($given_time) >= time()+300) echo "You are online";
```

But can't find anything on SO to do exactly this in javascript.
I want to check if the difference between a given time and the current time is less than 45mins

For instance

```
$scope.given_time = "14:10:00"
$scope.current_time = new Date();
```

I'm only concerned with the time part. I need to extract time part from `new Date();` and then compare.

Then this should be `true`

How can I achieve this with Javascript:

```
if ($scope.given_time - $scope.current_time < 45 minutes) {
   // do something
}
```

Comment: You can use `getMinutes()` for the date object.

Comment: did you tried by using plugin like moment.js ?

Comment: How often does it check for the time difference? If you used a window.setInterval and checked it every minute, you could use `getMinutes()` function and just compare it that way.

Comment: @www139 I do the check on every page load...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function checkTime(time) {
  var date = new Date();
  var date1 = new Date((date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear() + " " + time);

  var minutes = (date1.getTime() - date.getTime()) / (60 * 1000);

  if (minutes > 45 || (minutes < 0 && minutes > -1395)) { 
  // greater than 45 is todays time is above 45 minutes
  // less than 0 means the next available time will be tomorrow and the greater than -1395 means it will be more than 45 minutes from now into tomorrow

    document.write(time + ': true<br />');
  } else {
    document.write(time + ': false<br />');
  }
}

checkTime("14:10:00");
checkTime("16:30:00");
checkTime("17:10:00");
```

Comment: Can you modify this function to also check if current time (including date) is past the given time please... Thanks

Comment: @moh.ABK please can you ask a new question for that as it would change this one quite a bit

Answer (score 3):

Javascript uses unix timestamps in milliseconds, so it is similar to the output of strtotime (which uses seconds).

```
var date = new Date();
```

Then you'll need to do the calculation from milliseconds.  (Minutes * 60 * 1000)

You can also use `date.parse()` to parse a string to milliseconds, just like `strtotime()` in PHP does to seconds.

In full:

```
var date = new Date();
var last = new Date('Previous Date'); // or a previous millisecond timestamp
if ( ( date - last ) > ( 45 * 60 * 1000 ) ) {
   // do something
}
```

You could use a static date to compare just time, this is exactly what strtotime does if you exclude the date:

```
var last = new Date('1/1/70 14:10:00');
var date = new Date('1/1/70 14:30:00');
```

However, this approach will fail if you're trying to compare time that cross over day boundaries.

Comment: I don't want to consider `date`.. Just minutes. `new Date()` will give you complete date string

Comment: @moh.ABK You don't have to use the complete date string in your computation, you could use a static date, but you should. What happens if the timeframe crosses days?  11:59PM vs 12:01AM.

Answer (score 0):

There's a JavaScript method called getMinutes(); you can use to get only the minutes and compare.

Your code should look something like:

```
    var received_time = "14:10:00".split(':');
    var minute = '';  
    if(received_time.length === 3) {
      minute = parseInt(received_time[1], 10);
   }
    $scope.given_time = minute;
    var the_time = new Date();
    $scope.current_time = the_time.getMinutes();
```

And you now can do your thing:

```
if ($scope.given_time - $scope.current_time < 45 minutes) {
   // do something
}
```

Comment: That can't be used to calculate differences very easily.  11:01 would return 1 and 10:59 would return 59.

Comment: -58 compare with 45 as the OP want should work because obviously -58 is smaller than 45

Comment: I suppose it would work in that case but it doesn't logically make sense.  Try different numbers.  9:50 and 10:40.  50 minutes has passed, but it would be -10.

Answer (score 0):

Using a library like moment.js you can simply diff the two times.

```js
var $log = $("#log");

/* Difference between just times */
$log.append("Difference between times\n");
var givenTime = moment("14:10:00", "HH:mm:ss");
var minutesPassed = moment("14:30:00", "HH:mm:ss").diff(givenTime, "minutes");

$log.append("Minutes passed: " + minutesPassed + "\n");

if (minutesPassed < 45) {
  $log.append(minutesPassed + " minutes have elapsed. Event Triggered." + "\n");
}


/* Better: Difference between times that have dates attached to them and cross a day boundary. */
$log.append("\n\nDifference between dates with times\n");
givenTime = moment("2015-12-03 23:33:00");
minutesPassed = moment("2015-12-04 00:14:00").diff(givenTime, "minutes");

$log.append("Minutes passed: " + minutesPassed + "\n");

if (minutesPassed < 45) {
  $log.append(minutesPassed + " minutes have elapsed. Event Triggered." + "\n");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<p>Results:</p>
<hr>
<pre id="log"></pre>
<hr>
```

**Caveat:** If the given time is *yesterday* such as *11:30pm* and the current time is *12:10am* then you will get the wrong result. You'd want to use a date with the time if this type of thing is an issue for your use case.

**The moment.js documentation**

http://momentjs.com/docs/

**Angular directive for moment documentation**

https://github.com/urish/angular-moment/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Can you update your code to include date please. Also can I use the normal `moment` library in Angular?

Comment: @moh.ABK I've updated it with dates though you'll have to change it to work with your date format. If you're using the angular-moment directive then you should already have access to moment() in your application. You just need to inject it into your constructor(s).